# odeResponsive Mobile Menu style not working

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive mobile menu that kicks in when the browser width is 885 pixels. It does change from my main navigation  to the responsive menu  at that width however the correct CSS styling does not kick in until the browser is about 640 pixels wide.

Here is an example: http://www.concept82.com/DIS/menutest.html

The responsive menu does use javascript and I'm not very good with that. I found the menu and script off the internet a few years ago and I'm trying to make it work now. Thanks so much for any help!!

CSS for menu:

```
/* Responsive Mobile Menu */
.rmm {
display:block;
position:relative;
width:100%;
padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
margin:0 auto !important;
text-align: center;
line-height:19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.rmm a {
color:#ebebeb;
text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
display:block;
width:auto !important;
margin:0 auto !important;
overflow:hidden;
list-style:none;
}

/* sublevel menu - in construction */
.rmm ul li ul, .rmm ul li ul li, .rmm ul li ul li a {
display:none !important;
height:0px !important;
width:0px !important;
}
/* */
.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
display:inline;
padding:padding:0px;
margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
display:none;
width:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
display:none;
margin:0px !important;
padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
display:block;
margin:0 auto !important;
}
/*style*/
.rmm a {
color:#333333;
}
.rmm a:hover {
background-color: #6D0001;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list li a {
display:inline-block;
padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
font-size:15px;
}
.rmm-toggled {
width:100%;
min-height:36px;
background-color:#B30000;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.rmm-toggled-controls {
display:block;
height:36px;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:left;
position:relative;
}
.rmm-toggled-title {
position:relative;
top:9px;
left:9px;
font-size:16px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.rmm-button {
display:block;
position:absolute;
right:9px;
top:7px;
}
.rmm-button span {
display:block;
margin:4px 0px 4px 0px;
height:2px;
background:#FFFFFF;
width:25px;
}
.rmm-toggled ul li a {
display:block;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
border-bottom:1px solid #930709;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color: #B30000;

}
.rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a {
border-top:1px solid #930709;
}

/*media queries*/
@media screen and (max-width: 885px) {
#nav {
    display: none;
}
#mainnav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
.rmm {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 2;
}
#logo {
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    float: none;
}
```

JavaScript for menu:

```
function responsiveMobileMenu() {   
    $('.rmm').each(function() {



        $(this).children('ul').addClass('rmm-main-list');   // mark main menu list

        /*  width of menu list (non-toggled) */

        var $width = 0;
            $(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
                $width += $(this).outerWidth();
            });

        // if modern browser

        if ($.support.leadingWhitespace) {
            $(this).css('max-width' , $width*1.05+'px');
        }
        // 
        else {
            $(this).css('width' , $width*1.05+'px');
        }

    });
}
function getMobileMenu() {

/*  build toggled dropdown menu list */

$('.rmm').each(function() { 
            var menutitle = $(this).attr("data-menu-title");
            if ( menutitle == "" ) {
                menutitle = "Menu";
            }
            else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
                menutitle = "Menu";
            }
            var $menulist = $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
            var $menucontrols ="<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
            $(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>"+$menucontrols+"<ul>"+$menulist+"</ul></div>");

    });
}

function adaptMenu() {

/*  toggle menu on resize */

$('.rmm').each(function() {
        var $width = $(this).css('max-width');
        $width = $width.replace('px', ''); 
        if ( $(this).parent().width() < $width*1.05 ) {
            $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
            $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
        }
        else {
            $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
            $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
        }
    });

}

$(function() {

 responsiveMobileMenu();
 getMobileMenu();
 adaptMenu();

 /* slide down mobile menu on click */

 $('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
         $(this).find('ul').stop().show(300);
         $(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
         $(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
    }

}); 

});
/*  hide mobile menu on resize */
$(window).resize(function() {
adaptMenu();
});
```

sorry it's a lot

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: I stated what was not working and the example is using the simplest code. The issue is that the correct CSS styling for the responsive mobile menu (red background, drop down menu) does not take over at the intended browser size of 885 pixels. Between 885 pixels and 640 pixels the rmm does not adhere to the CSS styles given to it. Once the browser is 640 pixels or smaller the rmm displays correctly.

Comment: The point of my comment is (actually it's a quotation of an exact close reason), that you should add the relevant code to the question itself. Links tend to rot, or if the linked example is your real page, future visitors have no clue, why you asked the question after you've fixed the issues.

Comment: Gotcha, it was just a lot of code but I added the CSS for the responsive portion of the menu and it's java script. Thanks.